# Seed related model with dynamic attribute

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, php-7

I am trying to seed users with related images. Every user can have up to 5 images. Images table has a position field which is integer from 0-4.

There is my code:

```
factory(App\User::class, 50)->create()->each(function($user) {
    $user->images()->saveMany(factory(\App\Image::class, rand(2, 5))->make());
});


$factory->define(Goods\Image::class, function(Faker\Generator $faker) {

    return [
        'id'            => $faker->unique()->uuid,
        'position'      => ????
    ];
});
```

How to set position value that its value will be increasing from 0-4 (according to images number).

I also tried this, but position remains 0 all the time:

```
factory(App\User::class, 50)->create()->each(function($user) {
    $position = 0;
    $user->images()->saveMany(factory(\App\Image::class, rand(2, 5))->make([
        'position' => $position++
    ]));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Something :

```
$position = 0;
factory(App\User::class, 50)->create()->each(function($user) {
    $user->images()->saveMany(factory(\App\Image::class, rand(2, 5))->make([
        'position' => $position++
    ]));
});
```